# Oracle subquery using case statement in same query

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a case statement in Oracle; which I then require a subquery to use the results of the case statement all in the same query. How can I do this?

Here is the section of the query and the sub query:

```
CL.TC_DEFECT_1,
CASE
    WHEN CL.TC_DEFECT_1_SELECTION = 10000000 THEN 1
    WHEN CL.TC_DEFECT_1_SELECTION = 01000000 THEN 2
    WHEN CL.TC_DEFECT_1_SELECTION = 00100000 THEN 3
    WHEN CL.TC_DEFECT_1_SELECTION = 00010000 THEN 4
    WHEN CL.TC_DEFECT_1_SELECTION = 00001000 THEN 5
    WHEN CL.TC_DEFECT_1_SELECTION = 00000100 THEN 6
    WHEN CL.TC_DEFECT_1_SELECTION = 00000010 THEN 7
    WHEN CL.TC_DEFECT_1_SELECTION = 00000001 THEN 8
END AS "DEFECT_1_SORT_ORDER",

(SELECT TC_DESCRIPTION_FR FROM TBYE60_DEFECT_CODES DC 
WHERE DC.TC_CODE_DEF = CL.TC_DEFECT_1 
AND DC.TC_SORT_ORDER = DEFECT_1_SORT_ORDER 
AND rownum=1) AS SUB_DEFECT_1_DESC,
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know oracle, but you can read about LATERAL JOIN.
You can do something like that:

```
            CL.TC_DEFECT_1,
                "DEFECT_1_SORT_ORDER",

                    (SELECT TC_DESCRIPTION_FR FROM TBYE60_DEFECT_CODES DC WHERE DC.TC_CODE_DEF = CL.TC_DEFECT_1 AND DC.TC_SORT_ORDER = CL.DEFECT_1_SORT_ORDER AND rownum=1) AS SUB_DEFECT_1_DESC
    ...
    FROM
    ...
    CROSS JOIN TABLE(
    SELECT             CASE
                    WHEN CL.TC_DEFECT_1_SELECTION = 10000000 THEN 1
                    WHEN CL.TC_DEFECT_1_SELECTION = 01000000 THEN 2
                    WHEN CL.TC_DEFECT_1_SELECTION = 00100000 THEN 3
                    WHEN CL.TC_DEFECT_1_SELECTION = 00010000 THEN 4
                    WHEN CL.TC_DEFECT_1_SELECTION = 00001000 THEN 5
                    WHEN CL.TC_DEFECT_1_SELECTION = 00000100 THEN 6
                    WHEN CL.TC_DEFECT_1_SELECTION = 00000010 THEN 7
                    WHEN CL.TC_DEFECT_1_SELECTION = 00000001 THEN 8
                END AS "DEFECT_1_SORT_ORDER"
from dual

    ) a
```

OR

```
           CL.TC_DEFECT_1,
                "DEFECT_1_SORT_ORDER",

                    (SELECT TC_DESCRIPTION_FR FROM TBYE60_DEFECT_CODES DC WHERE DC.TC_CODE_DEF = CL.TC_DEFECT_1 AND DC.TC_SORT_ORDER = CL.DEFECT_1_SORT_ORDER AND rownum=1) AS SUB_DEFECT_1_DESC
    ...
    FROM
    ...
    LATERAL (
    SELECT             CASE
                    WHEN CL.TC_DEFECT_1_SELECTION = 10000000 THEN 1
                    WHEN CL.TC_DEFECT_1_SELECTION = 01000000 THEN 2
                    WHEN CL.TC_DEFECT_1_SELECTION = 00100000 THEN 3
                    WHEN CL.TC_DEFECT_1_SELECTION = 00010000 THEN 4
                    WHEN CL.TC_DEFECT_1_SELECTION = 00001000 THEN 5
                    WHEN CL.TC_DEFECT_1_SELECTION = 00000100 THEN 6
                    WHEN CL.TC_DEFECT_1_SELECTION = 00000010 THEN 7
                    WHEN CL.TC_DEFECT_1_SELECTION = 00000001 THEN 8
                END AS "DEFECT_1_SORT_ORDER"
from dual

    ) a
```

Comment: When I try the CROSS JOIN TABLE example I get a missing keyword error.

Comment: sorry, I do not have where to check Oracle syntax. I can just point.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand exactly what you want just in first look as I see you could easily use `INSTR` function instead of that case statement:

```
CASE
    WHEN CL.TC_DEFECT_1_SELECTION = 10000000 THEN 1
    WHEN CL.TC_DEFECT_1_SELECTION = 01000000 THEN 2
    WHEN CL.TC_DEFECT_1_SELECTION = 00100000 THEN 3
    WHEN CL.TC_DEFECT_1_SELECTION = 00010000 THEN 4
    WHEN CL.TC_DEFECT_1_SELECTION = 00001000 THEN 5
    WHEN CL.TC_DEFECT_1_SELECTION = 00000100 THEN 6
    WHEN CL.TC_DEFECT_1_SELECTION = 00000010 THEN 7
    WHEN CL.TC_DEFECT_1_SELECTION = 00000001 THEN 8
END AS "DEFECT_1_SORT_ORDER"
```

could be simulated as:

```
INSTR(CL.TC_DEFECT_1_SELECTION,'1') as AS "DEFECT_1_SORT_ORDER" 
--you need also to check if CL.TC_DEFECT_1_SELECTION in (above collection)
```

Hope this be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a subquery.  Define`DEFECT_1_SORT_ORDER` in the subquery, then use it in the outer query:

```
select . . ., DEFECT_1_SORT_ORDER,
       (SELECT TC_DESCRIPTION_FR
        FROM TBYE60_DEFECT_CODES DC
        WHERE DC.TC_CODE_DEF = CL.TC_DEFECT_1 AND
              DC.TC_SORT_ORDER = CL.DEFECT_1_SORT_ORDER AND rownum=1
       ) AS SUB_DEFECT_1_DESC
from (select . . .,
             (CASE
                    WHEN CL.TC_DEFECT_1_SELECTION = 10000000 THEN 1
                    WHEN CL.TC_DEFECT_1_SELECTION = 01000000 THEN 2
                    WHEN CL.TC_DEFECT_1_SELECTION = 00100000 THEN 3
                    WHEN CL.TC_DEFECT_1_SELECTION = 00010000 THEN 4
                    WHEN CL.TC_DEFECT_1_SELECTION = 00001000 THEN 5
                    WHEN CL.TC_DEFECT_1_SELECTION = 00000100 THEN 6
                    WHEN CL.TC_DEFECT_1_SELECTION = 00000010 THEN 7
                    WHEN CL.TC_DEFECT_1_SELECTION = 00000001 THEN 8
                END) AS "DEFECT_1_SORT_ORDER"
      from . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use clausole WITH,
where you could have your SUB_DEFECT_1_DESC,
and then use CASE where you would using the result of SUB_DEFECT_1_DESC.